# Debug .NET MAUI Android and iOS Simultaneously

Tags: maui

Is it possible to debug a .NET MAUI app in Android emulator and iPhone simulator simultaneously? I read somewhere that this was possible for Xamarin apps.

I tried running two instances of Visual Studio and use one to debug in Android emulator and the other in iPhone simulator but it didn’t work.

I’m trying to debug/test a chat app using SignalR and it would be wonderful if I could get both Android and iOS in debug mode at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried to use two Visual Studio with iOS and Android emulators to run the same empty MAUI project?